# NServiceBus Uri serialization/deserialization problems

Tags: xml, serialization, nservicebus

It seems to be a bug in NSB XML Serializer/Deserializer.
I have a simple command with Uri property like this:

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public MyCommand(int num, Uri uri)
    {
        Uri = uri;
    }

    public Uri Uri { get; private set; }
}
```

I set "http://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=1&id=0BzGD5JpB16DVTWNoemYyNkY3ZEk&ex" as Uri
It successfully serialized and stored in MSMQ.
But when my worker tries ti deserialize this message, i see this error:

```
ERROR NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiv
er [(null)] <(null)> - Failed to deserialize message with ID: 18df46d7-3768-4f79
-8c10-a3f700f6c1ce
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: An error occurred while att
empting to extract logical messages from transport message NServiceBus.Transport
Message ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '=' is an unexpected token. The expected t
oken is ';'. Line 4, position 45.
```

it looks like a Serializer problem becaue it doesn't quote & symbol.

Comment: What version of NServiceBus are you running?

Comment: my version of NSB is 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it looks like a bug (I tested it on V4.4.2 and v5.1.2)

[Opened an issue here](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2595)